# Custom Json Payload in Metric Alerts in Azure

Tags: azure, alerts, azure-monitoring

is it possible to create custom json payload for **metric alerts** like the way we create for log alert and log analytics alerts.If it is there is there any documentation i can refer to ,to create alerts with custom json payload

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to use a pre-written JSON and change it according to our context even for metric alerts. You can also deploy the JSON with ARM using any deployment method.
There are sample ARM Template for both static and dynamic instances given in Microsoft docs for reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-logs#configuring-metric-alert-for-logs